# Spark listeners for database loading

Tags: java, apache-spark, listener

I am trying to find the time for the following operation:

```
Dataset<Row> readDataFrame= spark.read()
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("url", drivingUrl)
                .option("dbtable", drivingQuery)
                .option("driver", driver)
                .load();
```

The action is called at the end of the application and I don't want to have a separate action for this due to performance cost.

I am trying to see if I can use spark listeners to calculate the time required for this. I have tried other approaches like spark.time() etc, but they are giving incorrect results due to the lazy execution of spark.

I was looking into the various methods in listener as well, but most were for stages/jobs. This is one `onOtherEvent` but I'm not sure how to integrate it to listen to the SQL connection. Also, I tried using SQL Listener, but you would need to know executor id for that, which I don't think we can know since it's spark who allocates executors.

Can anyone help me out here? I am very new to the concept of listeners and I am not able to find any good resources online for my purpose.

Comment: I don't know why this has been marked as already answered. That approach I have already tried but it doesn't work due to the lazy behaviour of spark. I have already mentioned using time package(which is similar to that) didn't worked.

Comment: You cant find execution time for that operation because you don't call any action on dataframe. Call readDataFrame.first();  and check sparkUI on  localhost:4040, there you could find how long it takes.

Comment: I call an action but at the end of the application. And I don't want to have a separate action for this as well, because it's taking a performance hit. And I checked in SparkUI, it shows job and stage wise results only.